# In the def. of a (k+l)-manifold with boundary, is it permissible for the domain of the coord. patch to be open in R^k x H^l?

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Studying Munkres's "Analysis on Manifolds" on my own. One exercise (#5, p. 103), asks the reader to show that if $M$ is a k-manifold without boundary in $R^m$, and if $N$ is an l-manifold in $R^n$, then $M \times N$ is a (k+l)-manifold in $R^{m+n}$. I proceed in the most direct way possible: I know that for each $p\in M$ there's a set $V$ containing $p$ open in $M$, a set $U$ open in $R^k$, and a continuous map $a:U\rightarrow V$ meeting certain conditions. Likewise I know that for each $q\in N$, there's a set $T$ containing $q$ open in $N$, a set S open in $R^l$ **or $H^l$**, and a continuous map $b:S\to T$ meeting certain conditions.

I can easily show that $V \times T$ is open in $R^{m+n}$. And it appears from the definition of a manifold (with boundary) that I need to show that $U \times S$ is open in $R^{k+l}$ or **$H^{k+l}$**. But neither of these follows if $S$ is open in $H^l$. I can, however, show that $U \times S$ is open in $R^k \times H^l$. This is the only sticking point, the rest of the proof goes through easily.

In the def. of a (k+l)-manifold with boundary, is it permissible for the domain of the coord. patch to be open in $R^k \times H^l$? Am I making some other fundamental error?

Comment: relate $H^{(k+l)}$ to $R^k\times H^l$

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. I just realized that I had a mistaken definition of H^(k+l) in mind. I thought all the coordinates needed to be >= 0 rather than just the last one -- doh!).